# Comparing records in same column and performing concatenation

Tags: datastage, transformer-model

My sample file is

```
101,name1,gold
102,name2,gold
101,name1,house.
```

I need to compare the names, if they are the same then the third column has to be concatenated using pipe deimiter
For ex: `101,name1,gold|house`
I need to achieve this in datastage transformer.
Please help on this

Comment: Could you post an example with your expected output ?

Comment: If the names are same then the loan types has to be concatenated by using a pipe delimiter 101,name1,hold|house

Comment: indentation and grammar changes

Answer (score 0):

- Sort by Col1 and Col2 before you enter the Transformer.
- Use a stage variable to concat col3 to previous Col3 (stored in an other stage variable) anfd reset it when LastRowInGroup is reached
- Use LastRowInGroup functionality as an condition to output data.